# Game State Tree for Golf Solitaire

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am working on a homework project in which we need to generate a state tree for the game of Golf Solitaire.  To do this I decided to create a `Move` class which represents a move from one stack of cards to another - simply put, it holds a reference to the two stacks involved in a single move.  Each node in my tree knows what it's move is.

The problem I am currently having is that my trees are much too large - like `OutOfMemoryError` too large.  **Edit** - I should note that when I make a tree for a very small game I do not get an error, but my tree is still much larger than it should be!

For those unfamiliar with the game: [Golf Solitaire Rules](http://boardgames.about.com/od/solitaire/a/golf_solitaire.htm). *Note* - We did not need to implement the restriction on playing a Queen after a King.

```
public void makeTree()
{
  _root = makeNode( null, null, 0 );
}

private Node makeNode( Node parent, Move m, int depth )
{
  Node node = new Node( parent, m, depth );
  ArrayList<Move> moves = findAllMoves();
  if( moves.size() == 0 )
    node.setScore( getScore() );
  else {
    for( Move mv : moves ) {
      mv.makeMove();
      Node child = makeNode( node, mv, depth++ );
      node.addChild( child );
      mv.undoMove();
    }
  }
  return node;
}

private ArrayList<Move> findAllMoves()
{
  ArrayList<Move> moves = new ArrayList<Move>();

  for( int i = 0; i < numPlayPiles; i++ ) {
    if( _play[i].size() != 0 ) {
       if( Math.abs( _play[i].top().getRank().ordinal() - 
          discard.getRank().ordinal() ) == 1 ) {
          moves.add( new Move( _play[i], _discard ) );
       }
    }
  }

  if( _draw.size() != 0 )
    moves.add( new Move( _draw, _discard ) );

  return moves;
}
```

`_play[i]` is simply referencing a pile of cards in the game.

I realize this is a bit much of code to be posting in a question, but my question is simply about my logic. I have a suspicion that my error is in how I am returning `makeNode` yet I am totally stuck here.  Could anybody confirm my suspicion and/or possibly give me some guidance?

Comment: do you have to generate all possible move combinations because that's what I think this is doing? If you only have to generate a move combination just take the first one you get. If you have to generate a winning strategy it'll be more complicated but you can do something akin to a depth first search for a winning strategy (basically continue along a given path until you can't win then backtrack to the last decision made and choose another path and continue this until you find a winning path). The main idea is you'll have to remove the unused moves to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: We are supposed to generate a tree for every possible move combination, after which we report the total # of nodes, # of leaf nodes (end of game), and the highest and lowest score possible. Although I removed some of the code from the question, each internal node's score is set to the highest score of its children, thus we can follow the tree down to the best possible score.

Comment: Ok, one thing I would recommend is making sure there are no cycles. Use a Debugger and see if you can generate a case where there is a cycle in your tree. If there is then that means something is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who is curious, my issue was one of not reading the assignment properly.  Specifically, my `findAllMoves` method was the issue.  A node should have *either* a move from the draw pile or all possible moves from play piles, but not both.  My code above allows each child, even at the same depth, to each create a `Move` from the draw pile to discard pile - resulting in a huge amount of duplicate nodes.

It also never checks the end-game conditions. As a result, each leaf node was either a losing score, or 0 (the method would recurse until the draw pile was empty even if the player already won).